# Next.js 13.4.13 Multiple Middleware

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

I have 2 middlewares. but always first middleware execute. I have to execute `return middleware(request, event)` this function to execute other middleware. But if I return this I can't return `return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl)`. NextResponse.rewrite doesn't work if I don't return that

withLanguage:

```js
export function withMultiLanguage(middleware: NextMiddleware) {
  return async (request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) => {
    const languageCookie = request.cookies.get("localeCookie")?.value
    console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname)

    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
    if (!languageCookie) {
      let locale = getLocale(request) ?? defaultLocale
      const newUrl = new URL(`/${locale}${pathname}`, request.nextUrl)

      return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl)
    }
    const newUrl = new URL(`/${languageCookie}${pathname}`, request.nextUrl)

    if (languageCookie) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl)

    }
    return middleware(request, event)

  }
}
```

withAuth:

```js
export function withAuth(middleware: NextMiddleware) {
  return async (request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) => {
    console.log("middlware")
    return authentication(request, {
      loginPath: "/api/login",
      logoutPath: "/api/logout",
      apiKey: authConfig.apiKey,
      cookieName: authConfig.cookieName,
      cookieSerializeOptions: authConfig.cookieSerializeOptions,
      cookieSignatureKeys: authConfig.cookieSignatureKeys,
      serviceAccount: authConfig.serviceAccount,
      handleValidToken: async ({ token, decodedToken }) => {
        // Authenticated user should not be able to access /login, /register and /reset-password routes
        if (PUBLIC_PATHS.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
          return redirectToHome(request);
        }
  
        return NextResponse.next();
      },
      handleInvalidToken: async () => {
        return redirectToLogin(request);
      },
      handleError: async (error) => {
        console.error("Unhandled authentication error", { error });
        return redirectToLogin(request);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

chain:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextMiddleware } from 'next/server'

type MiddlewareFactory = (middleware: NextMiddleware) => NextMiddleware

export function chain(
  functions: MiddlewareFactory[],
  index = 0
): NextMiddleware {
  const current = functions[index]

  if (current) {
    const next = chain(functions, index + 1)
    return current(next)
  }

  return () => NextResponse.next()
}
```

middleware.ts

```js
import { withAuth } from "./middlewares/AuthenticationMiddleware"
import { withMultiLanguage } from "./middlewares/MultiLanguageMiddleware"
import { chain } from "./middlewares/chain"



export default chain([withMultiLanguage, withAuth])

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/((?!_next|favicon.ico|api|.*\\.).*)",
    "/api/login",
    "/api/logout",
  ],
}
```

I expect all middlewares to work